# Dragging sprite with mouse and Cocos2d

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, ccsprite

i wrote some line of code, i can select sprite, and i can drag it, but as soon i drag it, it goes some pixels away from mouse cursor, and after that i can control it, but it's some pixels away from my mouse cursos.. seems like something wrong with my `CGPoint` convert, or i don't know, it's my code

```
- (void)selectSpriteForTouch:(CGPoint)touchLocation {
    CCSprite * newSprite = nil;
    for (CCSprite *sprite in movableSprites) {
        if (CGRectContainsPoint(sprite.boundingBox, touchLocation)) {
            newSprite = sprite;
            NSLog(@"palieciau");
            break;
        }
    }
    if (newSprite != selSprite) {
        [selSprite stopAllActions];
        [selSprite runAction:[CCRotateTo actionWithDuration:0.1 angle:0]];
        CCRotateTo * rotLeft = [CCRotateBy actionWithDuration:0.1 angle:-4.0];
        CCRotateTo * rotCenter = [CCRotateBy actionWithDuration:0.1 angle:0.0];
        CCRotateTo * rotRight = [CCRotateBy actionWithDuration:0.1 angle:4.0];
        CCSequence * rotSeq = [CCSequence actions:rotLeft, rotCenter, rotRight, rotCenter, nil];
        [newSprite runAction:[CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:rotSeq]];
        selSprite = newSprite;
    }
}

- (BOOL)ccMouseDown:(NSEvent*)event {
    CCSprite * newSprite = nil;
    CGPoint clickLocation = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertEventToGL:event];
    for (CCSprite *sprite in movableSprites) {
        if (CGRectContainsPoint(sprite.boundingBox, clickLocation)) {
            newSprite = sprite;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (newSprite != selSprite) {
        [selSprite stopAllActions];
        [selSprite runAction:[CCRotateTo actionWithDuration:0.1 angle:0]];
        CCRotateTo * rotLeft = [CCRotateBy actionWithDuration:0.1 angle:-4.0];
        CCRotateTo * rotCenter = [CCRotateBy actionWithDuration:0.1 angle:0.0];
        CCRotateTo * rotRight = [CCRotateBy actionWithDuration:0.1 angle:4.0];
        CCSequence * rotSeq = [CCSequence actions:rotLeft, rotCenter, rotRight, rotCenter, nil];
        [newSprite runAction:[CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:rotSeq]];
        selSprite = newSprite;
    }
}


- (void)panForTranslation:(CGPoint)translation {
    if (selSprite) {
        CGPoint newPos = ccpAdd(selSprite.position, translation);
        selSprite.position = newPos;
    } else {
    }
}

-(BOOL)ccMouseDragged:(NSEvent *)event {
    CGPoint point = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertEventToGL:event];
    CGPoint mouseLocation = [self convertToNodeSpace:point];
    CGPoint translation = ccpSub(point, oldMouseLocation_);
    [self panForTranslation:translation];
    oldMouseLocation_ = point;
}
```

Comment: When `ccMouseDragged:` is called first time after `ccMouseDown:`, what is the value of `oldMouseLocation_`?

Answer (score 0):

Some things you should consider:

1. on start drag, you should set oldMouseLocation as the point where the drag was initiated
2. make sure your sprites are dragged from their center. For example, if you're moving their container, you might drag them from their bottom-left corner
3. In your ccMouseDown you are not using the convertToNodeSpace function
4. You might consider moving the dragged sprite (selSprite) on the mouse location, instead of translating with the [oldMouseLocation - mouseLocation ] distance. Optionally you can apply some offset calculated on a [start drag point - dragged sprite position] distance

Answer (score 0):

I got it working, thank you.

```
- (BOOL)ccMouseDragged:(NSEvent *)event 
{
    CGPoint point = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertEventToGL:event];
    CGPoint mouseLocation = [self convertToNodeSpace:point];
    CGPoint translation = (mouseLocation);
    [self panForTranslation:translation];
    return YES;
}

-(void)panForTranslation:(CGPoint)translation 
{
    if (first) 
    {
        NSLog(@"%f, %f",translation.x, translation.y);
        deb1.position = ccp( translation.x, translation.y );
    }
    if (second) 
    {
        NSLog(@"%f, %f",translation.x, translation.y);
        deb2.position = ccp( translation.x, translation.y );
    }
    if (third) 
    {
        NSLog(@"%f, %f",translation.x, translation.y);
        deb3.position = ccp( translation.x, translation.y );
    }
    else 
    {
        NSLog(@"not in sprite's rect");
    }

}
```